# Upgrading Azure AKS without downtime

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I was looking for method to upgrade k8s version without downtime for Azure AKS and found this amazing blog post https://omichels.github.io/zerodowntime-aks.html but I got error at the start only

So currently running version of k8s in my region is no more available. When I tried to create a temporary nodepool got below error

```
(AgentPoolK8sVersionNotSupported) Version 1.19.6 is not supported in this region. 
Please use [az aks get-versions] command to get the supported version list in this region. 
For more information, please check https://aka.ms/supported-version-list
```

What can I do to achieve zero downtime upgrade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I upgraded without downtime, for your reference.

1. Upgrade control plane only. (Can finish it on azure portal)[image]
2. Add a new Node pool. Now the version of new node pool is higher(same with control plane). Then add a label to it, e.g.  **nodePool=newNodePool**.
3. Patch all application to the new node pool. (By nodeSelector)

   `$ kubectl get deployment -n {namespace} -o name | xargs kubectl patch -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"nodeSelector\":{\"nodePool\":\"newNodePool\"}}}}}" -n {namespace}`
4. Check the pods if are scheduled to the new node pool.

   `$ kubectl get pods -owide`
5. Delete the old node pool.

Comment: yes. able to create a temporary pool when upgraded control plane only. Thanks

Comment: Just quick question about this. Do you know if choosing "Upgrade control plane + all nodes pools" the upgrade will take place without downtime? What about if I only have one node pools with two nodes?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can I do multiple upgrades to control plane and later do this nodepool creation